# Retrieve and change logged in user MFA option adb2c

Tags: graph, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

Is there an option to get logged in user's MFA details and change option from SMS to Mail or vice versa using Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

For Azure AD B2C users, the MFA method is not controlled at the directory level. It is solely controlled by the configuration of the AAD B2C User Flow or Custom Policy.

In a User Flow, select your User Flow, click properties and you can configure the following MFA settings that all users will have: Email, SMS/Phone, SMS, Phone.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-user-flow

In Custom Policy you can control the options through many ways.

1. Using MFA Phone factor technical profile, the [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-factor-technical-profile#metadata) controls the options.
2. You can add in your own Email Verification screen, see this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email).
3. You could allow the user to use Email or SMS, see this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/pwd-reset-via-email-or-phone)

To get the users phone number via MS Graph:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authentication-list-methods?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: I have seen some latest graph API's are available to get MFA details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-list-credentialuserregistrationdetails?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http. will it be helpful in my case , also I have already implemented a custom policy for dual MFA option (Phone or Email) and whenever user is new It's working fine , the only issue is when we need to reset MFA for the user . I found Profile Edit policy will be helpful in that case but when I implement that policy I am not able to get any option to change the MFA for the user.

Comment: That graph link is not relevant for B2C users. As i mention, its controlled solely by the custom policy and possible extension attributes. Here is an edit phone policy sample https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/edit-mfa-phone-number